# Broadcast join in spark not working for left outer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have a small table (2k ) records and big table (5 mil) records.I need to fetch all data from small tables and only matching data from large table so to achieve this I have executed below query
`select /*+ broadcast(small)*/ small.* From small left outer join large`
Though the query return correct result but when I check the query plan it shows sort merged broadcast hash join.
Is there any limitations if small table is left table we can't broadcast and what's the way out then.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're looking to select the entire dataset from a small table rather than a large one, Spark won't enforce a broadcast join. However, if you change the join sequence or convert to an equi-join, Spark will happily enable a broadcast join.

**Eg:**

1. Big-Table left outer join Small-Table -- *Broadcast Enabled*
2. Small-Table left outer join Big-Table -- *Broadcast Disabled*

**Reason:**
*The reason for this is that Spark shares the small table (also known as the broadcast table) to all data nodes where the big table data is present. In your case, you need all the data from the small table but only the matching data from the big table. Spark cannot determine whether a particular record was matched at another data node or if there was no match at all, so there is ambiguity when selecting all the records from the small table if it were distributed. As a result, Spark won't use broadcast join in this scenario.*

Comment: I can understand if broadcast cannot be done if the dataset is too big, but I'm little confused with this point " Spark cannot determine whether a particular record was matched at another data node or if there was no match at all, ", why would there be ambiguity? the result of the join is still determined based on the matching criteria even it is on one node, isn't it? Can you please help me understand?

Comment: In a left outer join, at least one record from the left table should be included in the output. If there's no match at worker 1 for a record, sending it back to the driver, and subsequently finding a match on worker 2, can lead to ambiguous results. The output may include the record from worker 1 (without a match with the right table) and the matched record from worker 2. As you mentioned, if we only send record back to driver incase of a match, then it will be Equi-join not left outer join.

Answer (score 2):

Change the **`order of the tables`** as you are doing **left join** by broadcasting left table, so right table to be broadcasted (or) change the join type to **`right`**.

```
select /*+ broadcast(small)*/ small.* From small right outer join large
select /*+ broadcast(small)*/ small.* From large left outer join small
```

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a')],['id','name'])
df1=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a')],['id','name'])

#broadcasting on right df1 and performing left join
df.join(broadcast(df1),['id'],'left').explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(2) Project [id#0L, name#1, name#5]
#+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#4L], LeftOuter, BuildRight
#   :- Scan ExistingRDD[id#0L,name#1]
#   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
#      +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(id#4L)
#         +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#4L,name#5]


#broadcasting df1 and right join defaults to Sortmerge join
df.join(broadcast(df1),['id'],'right').explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(4) Project [id#4L, name#1, name#5]
#+- SortMergeJoin [id#0L], [id#4L], RightOuter
#   :- *(2) Sort [id#0L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0L, 200)
#   :     +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(id#0L)
#   :        +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#0L,name#1]
#   +- *(3) Sort [id#4L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#4L, 200)
#         +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#4L,name#5]
```

Comment: Thanks @Shu for answer.but in my scenario I need all data from small tables.But the join type you mention giving me all data from large table.which I don't want.I want full data from small tables and only matching data from large table also I want to broadcast so there should not be any shuffle is there any way out.

Comment: You can increase the `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to your big table size by default its `10MB` then broadcasthashjoin will be performed!

Comment: Thanks again but that's also not possible as my big size is more than 10gb which I don't think supported by spark to broadcast.                 Please let me know if there is any other way out.